# connecting no authentication apache hive with MicroStrategy

Tags: hadoop, hive, odbc, microstrategy

I have installed MicroStrategy BI tool, and Apache Hive-1.1.x with Hadoop services.

Started `hiveserver2` and `hadoop services`. And tested the connection, working perfectly. I'm not using any authentication to run this services.

Have any option to connect Non-SASL Apache hive server with MicroStrategy?
Without User and password can't able to create DSN in MicroStrategy.

I used following steps to connect with apache hive
*'Add New Datasource->Hadoop->DSN-less Datasource->Apache Hive'*
[image]

If I give any unknown value in User and Password mean throw following error

```
There is an error. Details
(Database error <5>: Connect failed. Error type: Odbc error. Odbc operation 
attempted: SQLDriverConnect. [S1000:5: on HDBC] [MicroStrategy][ThriftExtension] 
(5) Error occurred while contacting server: No more data to read.. This could be 
because you are trying to establish a non-SSL connection to a SSL-enabled 
server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem in *hive-site.xml*, for *hive.server2.authentication* value have to use as NONE. `NOSASL` is raw transport, which have username and password.

Add following property in *hive-site.xml*

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>NONE</value>
    <description>
      Expects one of [nosasl, none, ldap, kerberos, pam, custom].
      Client authentication types.
        NONE: no authentication check
        LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication
        KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication
        CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider
                (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)
        PAM: Pluggable authentication module
        NOSASL:  Raw transport
    </description>
  </property>
```